# Clear file system cache on AIX

Tags: aix, cache, jfs

I'm using AIX 6.1 and for testing.
I want to clear the file system cache.
Something similar a this on linux : `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Failing an actual method to flush the cache you might be able to get away with tuning some VMM parameters to effectively flush your cache.

```
vmo -L
```

Look at setting `minperm%` and `maxperm%` very low and `strict_maxperm` to 1. I don't have an AIX box handy to test what values it will let you set but I'm assuming 0 would fail, maybe:

```
vmo -o minperm%=1 -o maxperm%=1 -o strict_maxperm=1 -o minclient%=1 -o maxclient%=1
```

Monitor with `vmstat -v` to see when/if it applies. You might need to do something memory intensive to trigger the page replacement daemon into action and take care of that 1%.

```
cat "somefile_sized_1%_of_memory" > /dev/null
```

Then reset them back to your normal values.

Comment: Perfectly and acceptable workaround! I just set the `maxclient%` to a value equal of minperm% and `strict_maxclient=1`, in less of 2 minutes 16GB of memory was freed. Now I will back the original values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could find was this command :

```
mount -o rbrw
```

Link : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014315545#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014315663

Other option will be unmonting the file-system wich will dump the cache.

Comment: Hy @Boogy, I already tested this before... not work for me because  I need execute the command with users accessing the FS. This option  need to umount first, which make it unfeasible.